# Two Java Dates have Different Formats

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity class that represents an object brought over from MySQL.  One of the fields is a MySQL DateTime field that I've mapped via Hibernate as

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date effdate;
```

However, if that date happens to be null from the database, I want to set it to the current date in the setter method.  As I understand it, Hibernate does not support defaults, and to default the field with a ***columnDefinition*** clause would tie the implementation to a vendor.

When the field is properly populated in MySQL it looks like the 2nd output line.  When I default it, it looks like the first.  Shouldn't two date fields look the same?  If it won't be a problem in the end, I won't worry about it, but I'd like to understand how a Date object can appear differently.  I am aware of ***SimpleDateFormat,*** but not sure if it's coming into play here, since both are just date objects.  Is the @Temporal annotation doing something to it?

```
Tue Apr 24 14:34:10 EDT 2012  <- my default
2012-04-24 00:00:00.0         <- from MySQL
```

The setter method

```
public void setEffdate(Date effdate) {
// TODO if effdate is null use "d"

    Date d = new Date();
    this.effdate = effdate;

    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(this.effdate + "\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to understand how a Date object can appear differently

There are two concrete classes called `Date`: [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). The latter extends the former and formats the date as "2012-04-24".

> both are just date objects

They are almost certainly instances of the two different types, which explains the difference in behaviour. The one you're getting from MySQL is probably `java.sql.Date` and the default one you're creating yourself is probably `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the coalesce function to specify default from the database and not in java ?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

otherwise aix is right, you should check your imports